# PHP - In an array like 1,3,6,7; how to select row 3? (lowest number below 6)

Tags: php

I have an obscure array that follows product ID's and the respective details.

Here is an example of the array output :

```
id - 1
stockCode - 113
Desc - Printer 1
Cost - R 113.00

id - 3
stockCode - 133
Desc - Printer 3
Cost - R 133.00

id - 6
stockCode - 163
Desc - Printer 6
Cost - R 163.00

id - 7
stockCode - 
Desc - Printer 6 Details
Cost - 

id - 8
stockCode - 
Desc - Printer 6 Extra
Cost -
```

For a reason that is too long to explain, i would like to be able to loop through this array and within that loop and produce a certain outcome.

That being that any ID with data in only the second value and nothing in the first and third values, gets the second value appended to the preceding 2nd value of the key (ID) that came before the **Here is where i get stuck** current id. Once this has been done, the key must be deleted and the process continues.

Here is the code for that, the array is named $csvarray and $key would relate to the "id" in my example:

```
# Clean array - append 2nd values to previous values
foreach($csvarray as $key=>$val)
{   
    // Imagine this is ID # 7 in the loop
    if ($val[0] == '' && $val[1] !== '' && $val[2] == '')
    {
        $writeTo = HOW TO I SELECT THE KEY BEFORE 7, IN THIS CASE 6
                   BUT IF IT WAS 6, THE KEY WOULD BE 3
        $csvarray[$writeTo][1] = $csvarray[$writeTo][1] . ', ' . $val[1];
        unset($csvarray[$key]);
    }
}
```

So in essence, i would like a find a way to select the key value preceding the current value while looping through an array...

If anyone would like to share some knowledge or has a suggestion or advice or any kind of input on this question, it would be great to hear!

Thank you!

EDIT :

Thanks for all your input! Given the input the correct approach would be something like this :

```
# Clean array - append 2nd values to preceeding key second value
$writeTo = null;
foreach($csvarray as $key=>$val)
{   
    if ($val[0] == '' && $val[1] !== '' && $val[2] == '')
    {
        $csvarray[$writeTo][1] = $csvarray[$writeTo][1] . ', ' . $val[1];
        unset($csvarray[$key]);
    }
    else 
    {
        $writeTo = $key; 
    }
}
```

Comment: you just need a simple state machine. keep the "previous" value. if the value on the current loop iteration matches, the previous value gets pulled out.

Comment: As simple as `$prev = $val` at the end of each iteration...

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for all the help, see my edit for what i assume is the correct approach?

Comment: @deceze Thanks for all the help, see my edit for what i assume is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't that be in the else ?? if I understood well

all you have to do is that after the end of your if statement

```
if {
    ....
}
else {
   $writeTo=$key;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input but it should not be in the else, IF (first line is empty, second line is populated, third line is empty) -> append second line to preceding keys' second line. Does that makes sense?

Comment: if key 1 is empty key 2 is filled key 3 is empty, what do you want to append to what?

Comment: You are my hero :) It took some head scratching but i finally understand what you were trying to say. This is the perfect solution! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable to hold the last key checked:

```
$csvarray = array(1 => array(113, 'Printer 1', 'R 113.00'), 3 => array(133, 'Printer 3', 'R 133.00'), 6 => array(163, 'Printer 6', 'R 163.00'), 7 => array('', 'Printer 6 Details', ''));
$lastKey = null;

foreach(array_keys($csvarray) as $key) {
      $val = $csvarray[$key];   
    if ($val[0] == '' && $val[1] !== '' && $val[2] == '') {
        if ($lastKey != null) {
            $csvarray[$lastKey][1] = $csvarray[$lastKey][1] . ', ' . $val[1];
            unset($csvarray[$key]);
        }
    }
    $lastKey = $key;
}

print_r($csvarray);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. This is what Marc B has suggested but i see a problem in this. Say there is ID 8, exactly like ID 7; If 7 gets deleted and on line 8, the previous key will not exist, it was deleted?

Comment: Surely this is correct or very close.  If there is a possibility that the previous key has been unset and you would like to push the change down to the 'previous'->'previous' element,  then $lastkey needs to be an array and you can check the last value, if you unset a key, and $lastkey[count($lastkey) -1] == key to be unset,  take the top value off the $lastkey array.

Comment: @Gavin Although it is close, the problem with this as i see it would come if there were more than one line following each other that need to be deleted, by renewing the $lastKey value for every key you would create an error if the previous key had been deleted. You would only need to renew the key value if the line was not deleted, specified with an `else` clause. What if there were several of these lines that needed appending?